# Return value for function instead of inner function in Array.forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, return

I am using this code to check if something is valid

```
function isValid(source, target) {
  arr.forEach(function (el) {
    if (el.value === 3) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  return true;
}
```

The problem is that the `return false` line of code will only terminate the inner function in `forEach` and not the entire `isValid` function.

How do I terminate the outer function?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a "normal" for loop for this?

Comment: Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for checking the elements

```
function isValid(source, target) {
    return arr.every(function (el) {
        return el.value !== 3;
    });
}
```

The same with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
function isValid(source, target) {
    return !arr.some(function (el) {
        return el.value === 3;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

See [the documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a Boolean return value, you can use every() or some() instead. If available, the new methods find() or findIndex() can be used for early termination upon true predicates as well.

Answer (score 0):

Will be good to use regular `for in`, but with `forEach` you can do:

```
function isValid(source, target) {
  var r = true;
  arr.forEach(function (el) {
    if (el.value === 3) {
      r = false;
      return false; // terminate loop
    }
  });

  return r;
}
```